# error when i execute the makemigrations command in django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm following the cs50 course, i have added a new passenger model in models.py file but cant execute the makemigration command.
i pretty new to django, excuse me if im asking something obvious

## This is my models.py code

```
from django.db import models

class Airport(models.Model):
    city=models.CharField(max_length=64)
    code=models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.city} ({self.code})"

# Create your models here.
class Flights(models.Model):
    origin=models.ForeignKey(Airport , on_delete= models.CASCADE , related_name="departures")
    destination=models.ForeignKey(Airport , on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name="arrivals")
    duration=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f" {self.origin} to {self.destination} : {self.duration}"
    
class Passenger(models.Model):
    first=models.CharField(max_length=24)
    last=models.CharField(max_lenght=24)
    flight=models.ManyToManyField(Flights , blank=True , related_name="passengers")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first} {self.last}"
```

## This is the error im getting, I couldnt find anything online that explained this issue

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\practice\airlines\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\practice\airlines\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\faisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\faisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\faisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\faisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\faisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\faisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\practice\airlines\flights\models.py", line 19, in <module>
    class Passenger(models.Model):
  File "D:\practice\airlines\flights\models.py", line 21, in Passenger
    last=models.CharField(max_lenght=24)
  File "C:\Users\faisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1139, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'


im actually folowing the cs50 course

i cant understand what went wrong

before two models(flights and airport worked fine), but passenger model is not working
```

Comment: This is your typo error in Passanger model field last=models.CharField(max_lenght=24). should be max_length not max_lenght. written clearly in error message.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to look at the error and you can find the answer easily:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_lenght'`
means that you have `max_lenght` somewhere in your code that django doesn't understand what it means, all you gotta do is search for it, and replace it with correct phrase which in this case is `max_length`.

the error is raising from this model:

```
class Passenger(models.Model):
    first=models.CharField(max_length=24)
    last=models.CharField(max_length=24) #here
    flight=models.ManyToManyField(Flights , blank=True , related_name="passengers")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first} {self.last}"
```

Read error messages and stack traces more.